# Sending data between views in Django

Tags: python, django, session

I want to send data between 2 views in Django. Main logic is that on main mage I have a simple form where I input url. After submit I **scrape** data from this url and redirect to endpoint /bokeh. From this endpoint I want to go to endpoint /days (from the navbar) and operate on the same given URL. I was trying to use session, but it didn't work well. My code looks like:

**views.py**

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        url = request.POST['url']
        request.session['url'] = url
        return redirect('bokeh',url=url)
    return render(request,'home.html')

def bokeh(request,url):
    cl = CalculationLogic()
    return cl.get_data_from_url(request,url)

def days(request,url):
    cl = CalculationLogic()
    url = request.session.get('url')
    return cl.show_days_of_the_week(request,url)
```

So, after sending data from home.html to bokeh, everything is fine and I do my CalculationLogic. When I want to go to days I get NoReverse Match error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /days/https://github.com/USER/PROJECT/commits/master
Reverse for 'days' with keyword arguments '{'url': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['days/(?P<url>.+)']
```

and my urls looks like:

```
urlpatterns = [
....
url(r'^days/(?P<url>.+)',views.days,name='days'),
....
]
```

in my base.html file I have:

```
<body>
<nav>
<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'days' url=url %}">Days</a>
</nav>
</body>
```

Does anyone know why this soulution does not work?

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you forget to assign a value in your home view: `request.session['url'] = url` ?